# Not able login in my facebook integration with android app using different user id

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have implemented an app where I user can can post in their facebook account.
But when I login as developer account then its working, but when I use different user id then it showing a message "Authentication with Facebook failed! "

```
btnPostStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postStatus);
        edtPost = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.post_text);

        btnPostStatus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {

                facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
                restoreCredentials(facebook);
                messagePost = edtPost.getText().toString();
                if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
                    loginAndPostToWall();
                } else {
                    postToWall(messagePost);
                }
            }
        });
```

---

```
public void loginAndPostToWall() {
        facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,
                new LoginDialogListener());
    }

    public void postToWall(String message) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("message", message);
        parameters.putString("description", "topic share");
        try {
            facebook.request("me");
            String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
            Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("")
                    || response.equals("false")) {
                showToast("Blank response.");
            } else {
                showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Facebook: Go to Mannage App-> Select your App-> Settings- Change Sandbox Mode to off.
It works.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this line to your manifest

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/app_id"/>
```

and add app_id to your strings.xml file

Comment: @NightSky where can I turn off sandbox mode ?